# Extended class variable only returns NULL

Tags: php

Why does the `Teste` class variable return NULL in the`Recebe` class?

```
 class Teste
{
    public $Testando;
    public function GetTeste() {
        return $this->Testando = "Classe: Teste";
    }
}


class Recebe extends Teste
{
    public function GetRecebe() {
        echo $this->Testando;
        var_dump ( $this->Testando ); // NULL 
    }
}
```

Comment: because you havent called the function to set it to the string 'Classe: Teste'

Comment: You're not calling `GetTeste()` anywhere, that is where the value gets set.